# UART (PL011) Windows 10 IoT UWP on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: uwp, raspberry-pi3, uart, windows-10-iot-core

I created a UWP on a Raspberry Pi (Win10 IoT) to communicate with another device via the UART interface. The standard UART does not support parity bits. So I want to use the other UART (PL011). Does anyone have a solution how I can use the 2nd UART (activate)?

Answer (score 1):

The BCM2837 on Raspberry 2/3 has two UARTs, UART0(PL011) and UART1 which is mini UART. However to support the Bluetooth functionality the fully featured PL011 UART was moved from the header pins to the Bluetooth chip and the mini UART made available on header pins 8 & 10.
Raspberry Pi 2/3 supports the serial transport for communication through the PL011 UART. This is set by default in kernel debugging scenarios. An application or device driver can use the PL011 UART to send and receive data with the PL011 device driver turning off the debugger using the command `bcdedit /set debug off` .

Comment: Can I use the PL011 on pins 8 and 10 after disabling the device driver?